# Laravel Service VS Trait

Tags: php, oop, laravel-8, laravel-service-container

## Difference between service & trait in Laravel

Assume I have a class which handles image uploading on my application
Should I write it as service or trait ?
when i should use service and trait ?

Answer (score 0):

A service is a class that will be called during your file manipulation.

A trait is an extension of a class, that you can incorporate in other classes.

The choice is yours, I hope I understood you well.
Sincerely